# restrict dragging marker outside radius google maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

How to allow marker to be dragged within specific boundary and not outside that? Please help me out I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `OnMarkerDragListener` to get events every time Marker is dragged.

Assuming your boundary is given in `LatLong` object or `Circle` object that has some `.radius(boundRadius)`, inside `onMarkerDrag (Marker marker)` method use `marker.getPosition()` to obtain current location. Few ifs that will test if the marker is within your desired boundaries will do the trick. Once you are out of the boundary, make the marker not draggable using `marker.setDraggable(false);`. Make sure you reset back to `true` once  `onMarkerDragEnd (Marker marker)` is called or anywhere else.

Using simple addition and division of the center of your `Circle.getCenter()` and radius you can quickly find South-West and North-East coordinates and make `LatLongBounds` object that you can use to find wither user location is within the circle using `latLongBounder.contains(userLocation)`

Hope this gives you idea. I wish I had more time and give you actual code, but I think this will suffice.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will implement it and get back to you if I have any more queries.Thanks